# Microsoft Security Compliance Manager terms

Tags: security, group-policy

Recently i have installed Microsoft Security Compliance Manager. But i am confused with some terms. As per the print-screen ( which is mark in Red-Colour Round ) 1st - the 'Default' here means the default setting - which we get out of the box. 2nd - here 'Microsoft' means as per the Microsoft Best Practise & 3rd - What does 'Customized' means ( the Third Red circle )
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the explanation at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/compliancemanagement/thread/0d853d44-f0b5-422b-9f10-e5d88ae6ffbc/ :

""Default" is the default value for the setting in a pristine installation of the OS or application.
"Microsoft" is the value prescribed by our team in the Microsoft-provided baselines available in SCM.
"Customized" is the value you and your colleagues have prescribed in your own custom baselines. In other words, the "Customized" colun only has significance when you are working on custom baselines."